# Sinon Spy is not working when object is initialized with 'new' constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

I need a spy to check the argument of 'put' method for DynamoDb client(docClient). 
I never had problems with spies but in this case the instance is created by 'new' constructor and my instance (docClient) won't stubbed in fact it when is called the 'put' method store argument in dynamodb and when I check the spy the list of arguments is empty.

**articles/index.js**

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

exports.handler = async function handler() {
      await docClient.put({
        TableName: 'Articles',
        Item: {
          title: 'Title Example',
          body: 'Body Example'
        },
      }).promise();
}
```

**test.js**

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const mochaPlugin = require('serverless-mocha-plugin');
const sandbox = require('sinon').createSandbox();


const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
const { expect } = mochaPlugin.chai;

let wrapped = mochaPlugin.getWrapper('articles', '/src/functions/articles/index.js', 'handler');

describe('Articles Tests', function ArticlesTests() {
  afterEach(() => {
    sandbox.restore();
  });

  it('should store correctly a data', async () => {
    let docClientSpy = sandbox.stub(docClient,'put');
    await wrapped.run();
    const articleData = docClientSpy.args;
    expect(articleData.TableName).to.be.equal('Articles');
  })
})
```

***articleData*** is an empty array. But of course should not.

Answer (score 1):

`sandbox.stub(docClient,'put')` stubs a method on `docClient` instance that is defined in test.js. Since it isn't same instance as used in index.js, stubbed method has no effect.

Prototype methods can be spied or mocked on class prototype but this is specific to class implementation. `put` is `DocumentClient` prototype method, so this is allowed. Otherwise entire `DocumentClient` would be mocked, and since it's instantiated on index.js import, this would make testing complicated.

Since it's expected that `put()` has `promise()` method, the implementation should be mocked:

```
let promiseSpy = sandbox.stub().returns(Promise.resolve());
let docClientSpy = sandbox.stub(AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient.prototype, 'put').returns({ promise: promiseSpy });
...
expect(promiseSpy).to.have.been.called;
```